# difference between alert dismissal and alert closing in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie to twitter bootstrap, i am currently trying bootstrap version 3.
while i was going through these two lines of java-script code.

```
    $(".alert").alert()
    $(".alert").alert('close')
```

What is the difference between these two lines? 
And in which context each one is used?

Answer (score 1):

**$().alert()**
Wraps all alerts with close functionality. To have your alerts animate out when closed, make sure they have the .fade and .in class already applied to them.

**.alert('close')**
Closes an alert.

I recommend reading the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts